# How to Read Value of controls inside listview in xamarin forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my xamarin form project, i have a listview which displays the list of data.  Each itemTemplate contains a CustomCheckBox and EntryTextBox. Also, have a button outside of all these listview to save the data locally. When I press the button want to get the values of all controls inside the listview. How can I do that??

Comment: you need to bind the controls in the listview to a model, and then retrieve the values from the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following two things:

1.Create a model with the properties which you need to bind for the controls inside the listview.
2.Bind the model name to the listview.ItemSource property & model properties to controls inside listview.